# JavaScript radio button confirmation

Tags: javascript, validation, loops, radio-button, confirm

I am trying to add a function, or additional JavaScript to the existing function for a confirmation. I will need a confirmation box once the submit button is clicked saying, "You have chosen (either GCSE, A2 or AS), is this correct?" There should be a cancel button to return to the form or an OK which lets the form be submitted.

Here is the code, I did a little research and it said use a loop, I am very new to this so I don't know what to do.

```
<head>
<title>Exam entry</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function validateForm() {
var result = true;
var msg="";
if (document.ExamEntry.name.value=="") {
msg+="You must enter your name \n";
document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
document.getElementById('name').style.color="red";
result = false;
}

if(msg==""){
return result;
}
{
alert(msg)
return result;
}
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>
<form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="success.html">
<table width="50%" border="0">
<tr>
<td id="name">Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
<tr>
<td id="subject">Subject</td>
<td><input type="text" name="subject" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="examnumber">Examination Number</td>
<td><input type="text" name="examnumber" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" id="examtype" name="examtype" /> : GCSE<br />
<td><input type="radio" id="examtype" name="examtype"  /> : A2<br />
<td><input type="radio" id="examtype" name="examtype" /> : AS<br />
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateForm();"    />  </td>
<td><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: This code is running well or giving error what problem you face can you pls explain.?

Answer (score 3):

Set your radio buttons' values like this:

```
<td><input type="radio" id="examtype" name="examtype" value="GCSE" /> : GCSE<br />
<td><input type="radio" id="examtype" name="examtype" value="A2" /> : A2<br />
<td><input type="radio" id="examtype" name="examtype" value="AS"/> : AS<br />
```

Then use this script in your function to validate form or make it a function and call it from your function validateForm:

```
var checked = null;
var inputs = document.getElementsByName('examtype');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
          if (inputs[i].checked) {
           checked = inputs[i];
           break;
   }
}
if(checked==null)
{
    alert('Please choose an option');
    return false;
}
else{
    return confirm('You have chosen '+checked.value+' is this correct?');
}
```

Comment: no, -> -1, your solution consumes precious CPU cycles. You should `break` from the `for` loop once you found the checked radio.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning @Kira, have updated the code but one thing.. when you have only 3-4 radio buttons, its not about the CPU cycles, its all about the conventions.

Comment: indeed. Thank you for updating your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
add this to your code#

    function confirmation() {

    for (var i=0; i < document.ExamEntry.examtype.length; i++)
       {
       if (document.ExamEntry.examtype[i].checked)
          {
            var answer = confirm(document.ExamEntry.examtype[i].value)

        if (answer){
            document.ExamEntry.examtype[i].checked = true;

        }
        else{
            document.ExamEntry.examtype[i].checked = false;

        }
          }
    }

    }
```

Then add to you radio button's

```
( value="a2" )
( value="a1" )
( value="G1" )
```

And also add to your radio button's (onclick="return confirmation();")
remember to put this in all of you radio buttons
soz if this doesn't work.