# How to get radio button to display alert message

Tags: html, radio-button, alert

I want to get a radio button to display an alert when it is selcted, so the user can check that they have chosen the correct value. This is the code I have for the radio buttons:

```
 <tr>
     <td><input type="radio" name="level" id="GCSE" value="GCSE">GCSE<br>
    <input type="radio" name="level" id="AS" value="AS">AS<br>
    <input type="radio" name="level" id="A2" value="A2">A2</td>
 </tr>
```

How would I get so when any of these radio buttons are selected an alert is displayed to the user saying: "Are you sure you have chosen the correct entry level?"

Please keep answers simple, as I have only been learning HTML for 3 weeks

Comment: Read the answer of this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957604/javascript-radio-button-confirmation Possible duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
<input type="radio" name="level" id="GCSE" value="GCSE" onclick="alert('test');" />
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks man. This is so easy I can't believe I didn't realize to do this

Answer (score 1):

let's assume you have a form called # Myform

Then your code will be like this:

```
<form id="myForm">
<input type="radio" name="level" id="GCSE" value="GCSE" /> GCSE <br />
<input type="radio" name="level" id="AS" value="AS" /> AS <br />
<input type="radio" name="level"  id="A2" value="A2" /> A2 <br />
</form>
```

Then, put in a tag script something like this:

```
<script>
$('#myForm input').on('change', function() {
   alert("Are you sure you have chosen the correct entry level? +"$('input[name=level]:checked', '#myForm').val()); 
});
</scritp>
```

Hope this works for you!

Thx

Comment: It looks like you assume jQuery is available. Maybe add that to your answer?